# Не все песни прогружаются на сайте

Tags: php, html

Закинул на сайт несколько песен, но почему-то прогружаются не все. Прогрузилось 5, остальные грузятся только тогда, когда включаешь какую-то из первых 5-ти песен. Вот код выборки.

```
$result=mysql_query ("Select * from `primer`"); 
echo '<div id=spisok_muz> 
<h2> Примеры жанров </h2> <ul> '; 
while($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    if ($myrow['nazv'] != ""&&file_exists("music/".$myrow['nazv'])) 
    { 
        $muz='music/'.$myrow['nazv']; 
        $janr=$myrow['janr']; 
        echo'<li> <h3>'.$janr.'</h3><audio src='.$muz.' controls></audio></li>';
    }
}
echo'</ul></div>';
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подкорректировал код.

Comment: Профилирование в браузере во вкладке network что выдает по потоку?

Comment: Я не ас в программировании, потому я не понял вас =]

Comment: Для хрома жмешь F12, переходишь во вкладку Network, в фильтре выбрать All или Media, начинаешь песни включать и смотришь состояния запросов, когда не работает в каком состоянии запрос (status)?

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот.

Comment: В состоянии `pending` запрос в ожидании от вебсервера. Значит искать проблему нужно именно там, при работе с буферизацией.

Comment: Это проблема браузера ? Потому что в IE всё нормально.

Comment: Статику чем отдаешь, apache или nginx?

Comment: С помощью apache.

Comment: Попробуй перейти на nginx и сконфигурировать `fastcgi_buffer_*` возможно поможет решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [такой](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html) плеер. Есть поддержка плейлиста. Довольно просто й в установке.

```
<div id="wrapper">
          <audio preload></audio>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/02-juicy-r.mp3">juicy-r</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/03-its-all-about-the-crystalizabeths.mp3">it's all about the crystalizabeths</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/04-islands-is-the-limit.mp3">islands is the limit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/05-one-more-chance-for-a-heart-to-skip-a-beat.mp3">one more chance for a heart to skip a beat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/06-suicidal-fantasy.mp3">suicidal fantasy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/07-everyday-shelter.mp3">everyday shelter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/08-basic-hypnosis.mp3">basic hypnosis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/09-infinite-victory.mp3">infinite victory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/10-the-curious-incident-of-big-poppa-in-the-nighttime.mp3">the curious incident of big poppa in the nighttime</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/11-mo-stars-mo-problems.mp3">mo stars mo problems</a></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но когда я буду показывать сайт, то у меня не будет интернета, чтобы этот плеер отображался.

Comment: @Андрей, просто скачайте `audio.js` и подключите у себя. Тоже самое сделайте с `jQuery`

Comment: Вы думаете этот плеер исправить мою проблему  ? У меня с видео та же фигня. И я так понял что это происходит, когда загружается на одной странице много элементов.

Comment: @Андрей, Вы используете стоковые плееры. У них нету такой поддержки, как у кастомных. А для видео можете использовать http://www.projekktor.com/docs/playlists

Comment: @Андрей, и да - это решит Ваши проблемы с воспроизведением.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь. А то уже весь интернет перерыл в поисках решения.

Comment: @Андрейб всегда рад помочь

Comment: Правда я пока не особо пойму как его правильно подключить.

Comment: @Андрей, тогда пишите на почту romanko95.rk@gmail.com с темой "Подключение JS". С удовольствием помогу Вам